# Find the Taylor series for $f(z)=e^z$ about $z_0=1+i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series for $f(z)=e^z$ about $z_0=1+i$.

I know that I want to use the geometric series for $e^z$ which goes $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}...$, but this is centered around $z_0=0$. How would I go about changing this for $z_0=1+i$?

Comment: Just a small note: The series is actually not a geometric series. In a geometric series, each term is a power of some number, but the factorials in the denominator are not the same as powers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e^z = e^{z_0} \cdot e^{z-z_0}$, we have

$$
e^z = e^{z_0} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-z_0)^k}{k!} = 
e^{1+i}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-1-i)^k}{k!}.
$$

Comment: If I were to find the disc of convergence, would (-1-i) be my ratio?

Comment: If you want to use the ratio test for convergence, the ratio you would get is $(z-i-1)/(k+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

### HINT:

In general, the Taylor series is defined as follows:
$$
f(z_0)+\frac{f'(z_0)}{1!}(z-z_0)+\frac{f''(z_0)}{2!}(z-z_0)^2+\frac{f'''(z_0)}{3!}(z-z_0)^3+\cdots
$$
So what you have written as the Taylor expansion is actually a special case of this, since all the derivatives of $e^x$ at $0$ are just $1$. If you can find a way to express the derivatives of $e^x$ at $1+i$, then all you need to do is to plug those in.